# Cannot run MySQL after unzipping from a tar archive

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, osx-yosemite

After downloading mysql tar file archive, unzipped it in a directory (no installation).

Now when i run this from command-line:

/somedir/mysql-5x/bin/mysqld

I see following errors:

```
[Note] ./mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25) starting as process 5310 ...
[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/local/mysql/share/errmsg.sys'
[Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql/data/me-MacBook-[Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql/data/me-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
./mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql/data/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note] Binlog end
```

This is a mac machine, i have tried via sudo command as well - but that does not help.

Comment: can you take a look if the directory `/usr/local/mysql/data` exists?

Comment: Jens> Ofcourse that dir does not exist, becz there is no installation process involved, mysql is just unzipped in a custom dir, and i am trying to use it from there. This is how i was using in windows - and it should work perhaps with some config changes or i am missing something.

Comment: Ixer> what details can i provide?

Answer (score 3):

Try passing parameter `-b` or `--basedir=` for specifying the path to your installation directory. E.g.:

`/somedir/mysql-5x/bin/mysqld --basedir=/somedir/mysql-5x/`

Comment: scai> Yes! That helped a bit...now it seems to start but crashes with message: "[ERROR] Fatal Error: Can't open and lock privileges tables: Table mysql.user doesn't exist'

Comment: This is a different problem. You need to initialize it first via `mysql_install_db` as described in BK435's answer as well as in the MySQL reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql to run it properly. When mysql start running it reads various configuration parameters from configuration files which normally is `my.cnf`. Among those parameters there is one which tells mysql where is the `data` directory. `Data` directory contains schema, tables etc which are needed by mysql to get started.

It looks like for your version of mysql default data directory is `/usr/local/mysql/data/`. Since mysql is not installed it will not find data directory there.  Also i only mention one parameter i.e. `data` directory. There are various others which are required.

I suggest you to install mysql and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

While scai answer would get you passed your initial issue.  You will undoubtedly run into more issues. You cannot run mysql properly the way you are trying to.  You will run into errors and mysql will crash.  You have to initialize Mysql first.

`sudo mysql_install_db –user=mysql`

There are several internal mysql databases that mysql uses called:

`performance_schema`,`information_schema`,`mysql`

Without these databases  and the metadata files (such as `ibdata1` file) your mysql server will not function properly. Hence, the reason why you are now getting the error: `Table mysql.user doesn't exist`

These resources might help you in your current Mac environment:

http://akrabat.com/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-yosemite/

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: BK435> So what do you suggest? i do not have any file named mysql_install_db in the mysql-..\bin directory.

Comment: Y would anyone want to download from source, when there is a clear installable and a zip version to use?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with installation of mysql 5.7.11. 
The issue got solved after setting the /etc/my.cnf as mentioned below :

```
basedir=<somedir>/mysql

datadir=<somedir>/mysql/data
```